# Invoke jquery each not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    var lastForm = $(".frm_product_group").size() - 1;
    $(".frm_product_group").each(function (index) {
        $.post("save_new_product_group.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            if (data == false) {
                alert("Error: Try again");
            }
        });
        if (index == lastForm) {
            window.location.href = "product_group.php";
        }
    });
});
```

In above codes, window redirect to product_group.php without jquery.post(...). If I use alert(...) before window.location... line the jquery.post() update works fine. I guess it is problem of jquery response time. I could not sort it out.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the location change inside the callback for the post. It's changing the location (redirecting) before the post has a chance to complete.

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    var numForms = $(".frm_product_group").length;
    $(".frm_product_group").each(function () {
        $.post("save_new_product_group.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            if (data == false) {
                alert("Error: Try again");
                return false; // Prevent more posts from being sent after error
            } else {
                numForms--;
                if (numForms === 0) {
                    window.location.href = "product_group.php";
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Iqbal - what is happening? Is the window redirecting to `product_group.php`? Are any of the posts getting through? I suspect that only one post is getting through.

Comment: @Iqbal - Updated answer to deal with the multiple forms, since the server response can come back in any order and trigger the window.location.href change early.

Comment: @box9, Yes window redirecting successfully. but No post happened by .post. For your information, if I just add something like alert(index) before window.location.href the post also happen with successful window redirect. It is not good idea to pause the code for 1 sec before redirect.

Comment: @Iqbal - That sure sounds odd. Maybe other code is redirecting. Try removing the `window.location.href` line and see what happens.

Comment: @box: yes how to wait for all response has done. As I used (index = lastForm)... I could not think alternate solution...

Comment: @box: If I remove window.location.href then all post happen correctly. but then how can I redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a event.preventDefault call so the save button does not post the form

```
$("#Save").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lastForm = $(".frm_product_group").size() - 1;
```

Comment: nothing is missing and save button do not post the form. all are controlling by jquery. Problem might be in ajax response... but i cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on another day and yes it is a problem of jquery working too fast. My solution was to delay the call to the redirect with a setTimeOut(). 
Your code would look like that :

```
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        var lastForm = $(".frm_product_group").size() - 1;
        $(".frm_product_group").each(function (index) {
            $.post("save_new_product_group.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data == false) {
                    alert("Error: Try again");
                }
            });
            if (index == lastForm) {
                setTimeout("foo",1000);

            }
        });
    });

    function foo()
    {
      window.location.href = "product_group.php";
    }
```

Comment: I agree with box9. delay might be solution but not good solution. thanks user537417